# Does OpenFire or XMPP Protocol support Message Notification (Pending, Delivered, Read) like BBM (Blackberry Messenger)

Tags: xmpp, chat, openfire

I am a beginner and need help.

I am currently involved in a project, where required to build a chat application (server side and client side).
After further explore, eventually I was interested in XMPP.

For XMPP Server, I have been interested in the Openfire, which support XMPP Protocol. The question that remains unanswered is whether Openfire can be extended to the needs of Message Notification, which is a feature of the Blackberry Messenger which can determine whether a message is PENDING, DELIVERED, or has been READ by the client (user).

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7402027/8388

Comment: @Agung Pratama : Have you succeeded in this matter? I'm curious myself on how to do it

Comment: @danipralea unfortunately my project is discontinued, and I believe the Openfire doesn't support that features yet, please look at here: http://issues.igniterealtime.org/browse/OF-434

Comment: Actually I have succeeded in implementing it.

Comment: @danipralea wow, you implement it by creating the plugin? If you don't mind, can you share it how the concept and the implementation is done?

Comment: you need to send messages with the type property changed into whatever you want it changed to and in the app delegate in didReceiveMessage: you compare the types and do whatever you want to do according to your needs

Comment: Hey, have you solved that problem. I am also trying to get notification of message status such as pending, delivery, read. Please help Thank !

Answer (score 3):

As the (almost!) duplicate thread mentions, this question seems to be about XEP-0184.

See also:

XEP-0079: Advanced Message Processing
http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0079.html

Discussion thread: XEP-0184 Message Receipts
http://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/35128

Add support for XEP-0184: Message Delivery Receipts
[Status: Open]
http://issues.igniterealtime.org/browse/OF-434

Comment: so, does openfire will support XEP-0184 and XEP-079 later?

Comment: Hey, have you solved that problem. I am also trying to get notification of message status such as pending, delivery, read. Please help Thank !